# Calculate the step of a range slider with precision

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to build my own version of the HTML5 range slider and have ran into a problem.

I am current working out the step of the slider by dividing the slider width by the sliders maximum value.  I then work out the slider value by the position of it's handle and multiplying by the step.

What I am trying to work out is how sliders like jQuery UI's, set the step to a number eg: 1.  Surely the number of pixels restricts the amount of steps the slider can be divided by?

Comment: Show us your code, we will answer if pixels restricts the slider's steps.

Comment: figure out the value, then round it to the nearest step...

Comment: @dandavis but what if you stepping in 0.1 , the sliders width is 400 and the max value is 1000?

Comment: sliders are not very precise anyway, so you would have 400 slots along the value, rounded to the nearest step. you can't always slide every single value, not would you want to. if you need precise, go with an input[type=number]

Answer (score 0):

Sub-pixel positions are valid, quite common to see them too now that browsers support pinch zoom.

Comment: Thanks george, how do you get the sub pixel value from event object/ slider handle position?